# Discord.js canvacord

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js

I decided to restore my old bot for Discord. It starts and works, but until I try to execute the command "!rank", which was supposed to form a user card. It gives me the following error

When I wrote the bot, there was no such error. After going through similar errors, I didn't understand much

```
> (process:6848): Pango-WARNING **: 18:49:10.209: couldn't load font "Manrope Bold Not-Rotated 36px", falling back to "Sans Bold Not-Rotated 36px", expect ugly output.
> (node:6848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing discriminator!
at Rank.build (D:\Новая папка (4)\discord_bot\node_modules\canvacord\src\Rank.js:511:53)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> (node:6848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:6848) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a missing font. I would suggest reinstalling your node packages. If that doesn't work, try manually installing the Manrope Bold Not-Rotated. It is also only a warning and is replacing the font with an "Ugly" font so this shouldn't be the cause of the command not working.